# pointers and linked list with shared memory

Tags: memory, linked-list, shared

I want to get 2 programs to communicate, one (server) would store datas, and the other (client) would just access it.
I'll have to use a linked list to store datas because it won't stop storing, and then I was wondering if I could access to the whole linked list if only the first node is shared in memory.

What I mean is… are we allowed to access from the client program to the memory pointed by a shared pointer?

Sorry it seems obvious that we can not, so should I store my linked list into the shared memory, or do you think that would be awkward? 
Because if I do so, I'll have to declare a shared memory for every node right?

So, to add shared memory to both programs I need the same keys, but I don't know how many keys there will be, and I can't just store it for both programs, unless I would have had already a linked list…

so I used a very very VERY awkward method that I don't even know if it works right, but I wish you can tell, which is to use ftok that is supposed to take an (url,pid) and return a key. So I assumed it would send the exact same key if I used the same url and pid, using a fake pid starting from 0 that I would increment for every element I add to the linked list… what do you think about it? Any other way to do it which would seem less… crap?

```
typedef struct s_shared_elem
{
    char c;
    struct s_shared_elem* next;
    struct s_shared_elem* previous;
}shared_elem;

typedef struct s_shared_list
{
    s_shared_elem* first;
    s_shared_elem* last;
}shared_list;

int forthekey = 0;
char* url="/home/toor/Projet_cgi/";

shared_elem* shared_malloc(int pid, const char* url)
{
        shared_elem* shm;
        int shmid;
        int key=ftok(url,pid);
        if((shmid=shmget(key,1,IPC_CREAT | 0666)) < 0)
        {   
            perror("shmget");
            exit(1);
        }   

        if ((shm = shmat(shmid,NULL,0)) == (shared_elem*)-1)
        {
             perror("shmat");
             exit(1);
        }
        return shm;
}

void Init_shared_list(shared_list* liste)
{
    liste->first = NULL;
    liste->last = NULL;
}

void Add_elem(shared_list* liste)
{
    shared_elem* new = shared_malloc(pid,url);
    new->next = NULL;
    new->previous = liste->last;

    if(liste->first == NULL)
    {
        liste->first = new;
        liste->last = new;
    }

    else
    {
        liste->last->next = new;
        liste->last = new;
    }

    forthekey++;
}

void shared_free(shared_elem* todelete,int pid, const char* url)
{
    shared_elem* shm;
    int shmid;
    int key=ftok(url,pid);
    if((shmid=shmget(key,1,IPC_CREAT | 0666)) < 0)
    {
        perror("shmget");
        exit(1);
    }
    shmdt(todelete);
    shmctl(shmid,IPC_RMID,NULL);

    forthekey--;
}

void Delete_list(shared_list* liste)
{
    while(liste->last != liste->first)
    {
        shared_elem* tmp=liste->last;
        liste->last=liste->last->previous;
        Shared_free(tmp,pid,url);
    }
    Shared_free(liste->first,pid,url);
}
```

Comment: Assuming the maximum total memory requirement can be calculated and is within reasonable bounds, I would probably just pre-allocate a large enough shared buffer and then use offsets into that for the references. If your data is very dynamic you could maintain a linked list of free blocks within the same block, also based on offsets.

Comment: I get datas from USB, and the number of data I collect depend on time, one per second… I must admit that a buffer of 3600 elements would take 1 hour to be filled. You think I should go this way? Much easier to pass a buffer but well there is a limitation (with linked list as well you'll say, your memory has a limit itself)

Comment: What about using a database to store the data?

Answer (score 1):

In share memory you can insert a whole linked list. It is useful in many cases. You do not need to create a linked list of share memory (e.g. using previous key, next key ). All you need to copy each node of linked list to the shared memory.
for example .....
process2.c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/ipc.h>
#include<sys/shm.h> 
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int shmid,i;
    node *data; 
    if ((shmid = shmget(10, SHM_SIZE, 0644 | IPC_CREAT)) == -1) {
        perror("shmget");
        exit(1);
    }


    data = (node *)shmat(shmid, (void *)0, 0);  // node is linked list
    for(i=0;i<2;i++)
    printf("%d\n",(data++)->item_code);

    if (shmdt(data) == -1) {
        perror("shmdt");
        exit(1);
    }

    return 0;
}

process1.c

#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/ipc.h>
#include<sys/shm.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    node *SELL=NULL;     // node is linked list (structure) SELL is header
    insert(&SELL,"Soap",1,12.5,10);
    insert(&SELL,"Pen",2,20.75,8);
    display(SELL);

    int shmid,i;
    node *data;

    if ((shmid = shmget(10, 2*sizeof(node), 0644 | IPC_CREAT)) == -1) {
        perror("shmget");
        exit(1);
    }


    data = (node *) shmat(shmid, (void *)0, 0);
    for(i=0;i<2;i++)
    {
        *(data++)=*SELL;
        SELL=SELL->next;
    }
    getchar();
    if (shmdt(data) == -1) {
        perror("shmdt");
        exit(1);
    }
shmctl(shmid, IPC_RMID, NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

Run process1.c 1st then run process2.c